# Can I use old thermal paste?

Tags: computer-building, thermal-paste

I have some Arctic Silver 5 thermal paste from about 2 years ago.

It looks ok, but I want to know if it's still ok to use. Does thermal paste 'go bad'? It's been in a drawer away from light.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, they don't "expire" or go bad, but that is assuming that it has been kept fairly well sealed and not exposed to too much air.

In other words: if you can spread it and it isn't sticky/tacky or drying out, it should be okay

Comment: gah.. can't comment yet.. @DHayes, according to Acrtic Silver's site (http://www.arcticsilver.com/as5.htm) AS5 is not supposed to separate

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the paste, it may separate which can lead to uneven application of the heat transferring material.  Your best bet would be to contact Arctic Silver and ask them directly